# How do I print each character of a string but with 1s of delay in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, delay

I want to print "Hello World" on the screen but its each character one by one with 1 second delay. I've used setInterval() function but its not working. Why?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        function type(){
            var text = "Hello World!";
            var i;
            var o = "";
            for(i = 0;i < text.length;i++){
            o += text[i]
            document.write(o[i])
            
            }
        }

    var exe = setInterval(type(), 1000);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

We simply split our string into arrays and, when inserted into the page, delete the first element.

When there are no elements left in our array, we stop the timer.

```js
let str = 'Hello world'.split('');

const interval = setInterval(() => {
  document.write(str[0]);
  str = str.slice(1);
  
  if (!str.length) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

There're so many mistakes in your code, I don't know where to start...

Sorry to put it this way, but here's a cleaner version follows your approach, mind the comments:

```js
const text = "Hello World!";

// the timer reference
let timer;

// the current index
let i = 0;

// you don't need a for loop in setInterval, the function itself is aleady called in iterations, just treat it as a loop iteration.
function type() {

  // print the current charater with current index
  document.write(text[i]);
  
  // increase the index
  i++;
  
  // if the index reaches the maximum text length, cease the timer
  if(i >= text.length) 
    clearInterval(timer);
}

// pass in function, instead of calling it
timer = setInterval(type, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've made few changes with your logic.

`type()` function will only do char print.

`intialize` starting position with `0` and `text`.

when `i` is same as `text.length` `clearInterval`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var text = "Hello World!";
    var i = 0;
    var o = "";

    function type() {
      o += text[i];
      document.write(o[i]);
      i++;
      if (i == text.length) {
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
    }
    var interval = window.setInterval(type, 1000);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        function type(){
            var text = "Hello World!";
            var o = "";
            for(let i = 0;i < text.length;i++){
            o += text[i];
            setTimeout(()=> document.write(o[i]), i*1000);
          }
        }
    type();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var i = 0
        var o = "";
        var text = "Hello World!";
        function type(){
            if(i < text.length){
                o += text[i]
                document.write(o[i])
                i++
                setTimeout(type, 1000)
            }
        }

        setTimeout(type, 1000)
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  
</body>
  <script>
    var i=0;
     var text = "Hello World!";
       

    var exe = setInterval(function (){if (i<text.length)
                 document.write(text[i])
            
      
            i++;}, 1000);
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: please add some explanation to your answer.

Comment: There is no need to use for loop in the original code. The counter of present characters printed should be available globally rather that in function scope. Added if condition so that till the text has character, print the current character. Though there should be an else condition also to clear interval as provided by other answers to this question.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the concept of a *closure* and maintain the index of the character to be printed as a closure variable.

Each time the interval callback function is executed, the index is incremented and the inner function takes the current value of the index from the *lexical scope*.

Then once the length of the `text` is equal to the index, the interval is cleared:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    function type(text, idx) {
      document.write(text[idx]);
    }
    function start() {
      //The index to keep track of and increment from the timer
      let idx = 0;

      //The text to iterate
      const text = "Hello World!";

      //Set up the interval with a callback and form a closure
      const id = setInterval(() => {

       //Refers to the text and idx from the lexical scope
        type(text, idx++);

        //Once the index has reached the length of the text
        if (idx === text.length) {

          //clear the interval id
          clearInterval(id);

        }
      }, 1000);
    }

    //Invoke the main function
    start();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps?

```
const word = "Hello World";

function printWord(str) {
  if (typeof str === "string") {
    let curIndex = 0;
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (curIndex < str.length) {
        console.log(str[curIndex]);
        curIndex++;
      } else {
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
}

printWord(word);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 var interval = null
 function type(){
            var text = "Hello World!";
            var i = 0;
            interval = setInterval( () => {
             if( i === text.length -1) {
               clearInterval(interval);
               
               }
               document.write(text[i]);
             console.log(text[i++]);
             
             }, 1000)    
  }
  
  type()
```